# File upload not having the image path to be able to save to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload a file in my create method in my controller so on my form I have.

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="file" id="ProfileImage"  class="btn-primary float-left" name="FormFile">
   </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Save </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
```

In My Poi model I have

```
public string  ProfileIamge { get; set; }
```

In My Controller my create is like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,FirstName,MiddleName,Address1,Flag,Address2,City,County,PostCode,ProfileImage,LastName,Nationallity,Role,DOB,Age,Alias,PlaceOfBirth,CountryOfBirth,Deceased,DeceasedDate,AddressId,EmailAddress,FacebookUrl,TwitterUrl,LinkedInUrl,CopmanyName,CompanyAddress,StartDate,EndDate,isDeleted,isActive,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,Tattoos,FacialFeatures,Alias")] POI pOI) { 

var test = pOI.ProfileIamge;     
}
```

But test is not having the local image path can i ask as to why that is im using asp.net 3.1 and ef 3.1.7

I no how to upload the file once i get the value i just need to no why its not binding as it should.

Also how would one give a preview image once the file is selected.

**Edit 2**

I tried the following for the preview of the image

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <img id="imgPreview" src="" alt="" style="display: none"/>
      <input type="file" id="FormFile" class="btn-primary float-left" name="FormFile">
  </div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#FormFile').change(function () {
        $('#imgPreview').hide();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imgPreview').show();
            $('#imgPreview').attr("src", e.target.result);
          
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    });
</script>
```

But the image did not preview

Comment: Not to be nosey, but what's with that `Bind` command? Is that data from an Http Form? You could just do this: `public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] POI pOI)`

Comment: Also, can you show your `POI` model?

Comment: Hi @Andy the bind is created when you use the scaffold option its because i sometimes dont want to have certin fields being bound. Its 100% legal to use this option my model only needs to show the file uploaded for the example code it would be to long other wise for the post

Comment: Just a heads up, I tested your code on my machine and it doesn't work with the `[Bind()]` attribute, but it did work with `[FromForm]`.

Comment: @Andy Yeah I noticed that myself bind just not must work with the file box

Comment: @Andy im going refactor the code at the end of project anyway will get rid of those binds i only used the scaffold to get the project up a bit quicker.

Comment: @Andy in the second part of my quesiton how would one provide a preview image andy

Comment: You want to return a preview image to the person who posted the file? Or save an image somewhere

Comment: Preview  it first and then save it i already have it saving i just need to no how to save it before they submit the record.

Comment: Oh i have no idea -- i don't work in the Front End. I don't know how you'd do that with an MVC view. I would post another question asking that specifically.

Comment: me to mate am mostly back end i hate jquery lol @Andy agree 100% their with ur statment

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else this worked for me.

Make sure in your controller you use , IFormFile FormFile

for example

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,FirstName,MiddleName,Address1,Flag,Address2,City,County,PostCode,ProfileImage,LastName,Nationallity,Role,DOB,Age,Alias,PlaceOfBirth,CountryOfBirth,Deceased,DeceasedDate,AddressId,EmailAddress,FacebookUrl,TwitterUrl,LinkedInUrl,CopmanyName,PoiReason,CompanyAddress,StartDate,EndDate,isDeleted,isActive,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,Tattoos,FacialFeatures,Alias")] POI pOI, IFormFile FormFile) {
  int attachmentId = await UploadProfileImage(FormFile, (int)FileAttachments.UploadAreEnum.Poi, pOI.Id, 0);            
}
```

Then in my upload function I will have access to the file

```
public async Task<int> UploadProfileImage(IFormFile FormFile, int UploadArea, int PoiId, int VesselId)
{
     //do something with the upload create a record in the db
}
```

For the preview I used the following

```
<div class="form-group">
    <img id="previewImg"  src="/images/missing-profile-image.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>

</div>
<div class="form-group">      
    <input type="file" id="FormFile" class="btn-primary float-left" onchange="previewFile(this);"  name="FormFile">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
  function previewFile(input){
    var file = $("input[type=file]").get(0).files[0];
    if(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            $("#previewImg").attr("src", reader.result);
        }
 
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
 }
</script>
```